# Customised Error Message for default DateValidator in Wicket

Tags: wicket, wicketstuff

I'm using DateValidator class to validate the date entered by user. I'm getting generic error message for this. Can I customise the error message without creating a separate Validator class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for example if you have the following kind of page.

**MyPage.html**

```
<wicket:page>
    <form wicket:id="form">
        <input type="text" wicket:id="startDate" />
        <input type="text" wicket:id="endDate" />
    </form>
</wicket:page>
```

Then you add next to your java class a properties file named `MyPage.properties` in which you add the following entries.

**MyPage.properties**

```
form.startDate.DateValidator.minimum=<message for minimum startDate>
form.startDate.DateValidator.maximum=<message for maximum startDate>
form.endDate.DateValidator.minimum=<message for minimum endDate>
form.endDate.DateValidator.maximum=<message for maximum endDate>
```

You can use variables like `${input}` or `${label}` to be substituted in the feedback messages.

A good place to start is in the Wiki of Apache Wicket at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/x/N1IB

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [API Docs for DateValidator](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/validation/validator/DateValidator.html) i can see that based on the condition that failed wicket used different error keys ..like : DateValidator.range, DateValidator.minimum, DateValidator.maximum. You can use this keys and create your custom error messages for this situations.